# how to refresh ListView.builder flutter

Tags: list, listview, flutter, dart, builder

How can I refresh my ListView.builder when adding item to the list?

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: propList.length,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context,index)=> Text(propList[index]),
    )
```

my button is

```
FlatButton(onPressed: (){propList.add('text');}, child: Text('add'))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you've extended the `StatefulWidget`, you must call `setState` everytime you change the state. Ex:

```
setState(() { propList.add('text'); });
```

Here's a quick example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(home: MyList());
}

class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyListState createState() => _MyListState();
}

class _MyListState extends State<MyList> {
  List<String> propList = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My List'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: propList.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context,index)=> Text(propList[index]),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() => propList.add('text')),
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you a lots, that worked, and thank you to make it with an example.

Comment: what about deleting?
 setState(() {
      propList.remove(widget.propName);

    });
that didn't work

Comment: `remove` method takes the exact object that you want to remove. Or you can call `removeLast()` @Husamuldeen

Comment: how can Force Refresh be done on STATELESS widget..

Comment: @VrajendraSinghMandloi You can use provider package and use future builder.  Wrap ListView builder in  `Cosumer`

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `onPressed: setState(() { propList.length; });`

Answer (score 0):

Here I've created [flat_list](https://pub.dev/packages/flat_list) widget which has similar specifications as in React Native's FlatList. Below will simply work.

```
FlatList(
  onRefresh: () async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  },
  data: items.value,
  buildItem: (item, index) {
    var person = items.value[index];

    return ListItemView(person: person);
  },
),
```